# Помогите сделать Replace для блокнота в С#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Вообщем, я сделал стандартный блокнот, осталось сделать Replace. я не стал делать отдельное окно для поиска и замены и использовал стандартный элемент управления textBox. По моей логике функция Replace должна видеть слово из textBox1 найти все совпадения из RichTextBox1(там находится весь текст фаила) и потом поменять все найденные слова на слово из textBox2. Я попытался использовать много вариантов, но ни один не работает, так как я новичек в программирование выходит я чего-то не знаю для того чтобы решить эту задачу.
Если что, вот как я реализовал поиск:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            string allText = RichTextBox1.Text;
            string searchStr = textBox1.Text;

            if (allText.Contains(searchStr))
            {
                if (index > allText.Length)
                {
                    index = 0;
                }
                int selectionLength = searchStr.Length;
                int indexStart = allText.IndexOf(searchStr, index);
                if (indexStart == -1)
                {
                    index = 0;
                    indexStart = allText.IndexOf(searchStr, index);
                }
                int indexEnd = indexStart + selectionLength;
                RichTextBox1.Focus();
                RichTextBox1.Select(indexStart, selectionLength);
                //RichTextBox1.BringToFront();
                RichTextBox1.Update();
                textBox1.Clear();
                index = indexStart + 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

index это глобальная переменная

Вот куда надо писать Replace:

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то это делается так, в одну строчку `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);` Проблема может возникнуть только с потерей форматирования текста (жирный, цветной, большой), если таковое используется. Если форматирование не используется, то используйте лучше обычный TextBox вместо RichTextBox

Comment: я сделал меню для Font. Щас проверю

Comment: Сработало, я конечно неожидал такого поаворота событий, просто с поиском я немного помучился, спасибо. Но есть одно но, когда меняешь слово, всё выстраевается с новой строки.

Comment: А если вместо `textBox1.Text` использовать `textBox1.Text.Trim()`?

Comment: тоже самое получилось

Comment: ой `textBox2.Text.Trim()`

Comment: нет, тоже самое, возможно надо ещё что то добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichTextBox на самом деле сложный контрол. Чтобы с ним что-то сделать и не потерять форматирование, надо постараться. В частности не следует изменять его `.Text`.

Давайте попробуем так:

```cs
if (textBox1.Text?.Length > 0 && textBox1.Text != textBox2.Text)
{
    while (RichTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text) >= 0)
    {
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = textBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

Сам не проверял, но судя по документации `RichTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text)` находит и выделяет запрошенный текст. Так что для поиска можете использовать этот же вызов.

Документация: [RichTextBox.Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: не вышло, и ещё заметил одно, когда меняшь слово первыйф раз он его удаляет, если заного открыть тот же фаил и изменить то же слово, то только тогда всё слово изменится и как обычно будет с новой строки

Comment: возможно проблема может быть и в KeyDown

Comment: @Velk то о чем вы говорите, видно только вам. Не должно быть никаких новых строк. Вероятно у вас перевод на новую строку в `textBox2.Text` содержится, но в этом случае `Trim()` должен помочь. Уберите лишний код вообще и перепроверьте.

Comment: а вот на этот раз всё работает как надо

Comment: @Velk обновил код в ответе, добавил проверок

Comment: Спасибо, работает идеально